# How to solve the heat equation for functional boundary conditions and the step function as the initial condition?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

We are trying to solve the one-dimensional heat equation:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^{2}u }{\partial x^{2}}$.

The initial condition is:
$u(x,0)= u_{1} $ when $x < 1,$ and $0$ when $x \ge 1$.

The boundary conditions are as follows:

$u(0,t) = \frac{1}{t+a^{-1}}+a$

$u(L,t) = \frac{-1}{t+a^{-1}}+a$

$a$ here is a constant.

We are trying to figure out how to solve this equation. Should we go the Fourier series route to solve this(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToIXSwZ1pJU) or should we do separation of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When solving the homogeneous problem on a finite domain with time dependent boundary conditions you want to get the equilibrium temperature. So if we have

$$\begin{cases} u_{t} = k u_{xx}  &  0 \leq x \leq L , t>0 \\ u(x,0) = f(x)  , & 0 \leq x \leq L \\ u(0,t) = A(t) , u(L,t) = B(t) & t > 0 \end{cases}$$

In this case we need a candidate solution for the equilibrium temperature so we create a function called the **reference temperature**, $r(x,t)$ and we want the function to satisfy.

$$ r(0,t) = A(t) \\ r(L,t) = B(t) $$

we can create one like so

$$ r(x,t) = A(t) + \frac{x}{L}\big[B(t) - A(t) \big]$$

Now, instead we have

$$ v(x,t) = u(x,t) - r(x,t) $$

and this solution $v(x,t)$ will solve the homogeneous problem.

Ok, now that it has been set up we'll let

$$ r(x,t) = A(t) + \frac{x}{L}\big[B(t) - A(t) \big]$$

and now we replace $A(t) = \frac{1}{t+a^{-1}} + a$ and $B(t) = \frac{-1}{t+a^{-1}} + a $

$$ r(x,t) = \frac{1}{t+a^{-1}} + a + \frac{x}{L} \big [\frac{-2}{t+a^{-1}} \big]$$

---

Now, instead we have this homogeneous problem you should be able to solve

$$\begin{cases} v_{t} = k v_{xx}  &  0 \leq x \leq L , t>0 \\ v(x,0) = f(x) - r(x)  , & 0 \leq x \leq L \\ v(0,t) = 0 , v(L,t) = 0 & t > 0 \end{cases}$$

The solution to this is

$$ v(x,t) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) e^{-k t(\frac{n \pi}{L})^{2} }$$

you solve for the coefficients $a_{n}$ and we get

$$ a_{n} = \frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L} \big[ f(x) - r(x) \big] \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) dx $$

where $f(x)$ is your function

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}  u_{1}  &  x < 1 \\  0  & x \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

which looks like the complement of a Heaviside function multiplied by the constant $u_1$. Try that and see what happens.

---

This about the reference temperature function $r(x,t)$. We need a function such that it obeys the boundary conditions.

If $u(x,t) = v(x,t) + r(x,t)$, we have already said that $v(x,t)$ is the homogeneous solution. So $u(0,t) = v(0,t) + r(0,t)$ and $u(L,t) = v(L,t) + r(L,t)$. But $v(0,t) = 0$ and $v(L,t) = 0$.

$ x = 0$ we get

$$ r(0,t) = A(t) + \frac{0}{L}[B(t) - A(t)]  = A(t)$$

and at $x=L$ we have

$$ r(L,t) = A(t) + \frac{L}{L}[B(t) -A(t)] = B(t) + A(t) - A(t) = B(t) $$

which is what we wanted.

Comment: Hey could you explain where this comes from? (,)=(,)−(,)

Comment: @user1234 The solution $u(x,t) = v(x,t) + r(x,t)$ which is the sum of homogeneous solution $v(x,t)$ and the reference temperature $r(x,t)$. If you subtract the reference temperature you get $v(x,t) =  u(x,t) - r(x,t)$

Comment: Alright, but how did we change our equation to be in terms of v? Aren't we interested in u?

Comment: @user1234 $u(x,t) = v(x,t) + r(x,t)$ and I gave you both of those. $u(x,t) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) e^{-k t(\frac{n \pi}{L})^{2} } + \frac{1}{t+a^{-1}} + a + \frac{x}{L} \big [\frac{-2}{t+a^{-1}} \big]$, right?

Comment: Could you tell us how you were able to come up with the expression for $r(x,t)$?

Comment: @user1234 I updated it. Note that $r(0,t) = A(t) + \frac{0}{L}[ B(t) - A(t)]  = A(t)$ and $r(L,t) = A(t) + \frac{L}{L}[B(t) - A(t)] = B(t) +A(t) -A(t) = B(t)$. Those are the boundary conditions. If $r(x,t)$ equals those at the boundaries and we have $v(x,t)$ is the homogeneous solution (which is zero there) then it satisfies $u(x,t) = v(x,t) +r(x,t)$